# incorrect INSERT statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Food_Log
(Person,Food,ServingSize,Meal)
VALUES
('John','Cheerios',2,'1-APR-2014','Breakfast');
('John','TBoneSteak',1,'2-APR-2014','Lunch');
```

On the 5th line of this code I am receiving an error that says:

> Incorrect syntax near 'John'.

Not sure what this error means or is asking me to change.

Comment: You did not even respond to your last question.

Comment: i don't know how to respond to questions, i am just looking for some answers

Comment: Your questions are very simple. You can easily look that up in the documentation.

Comment: Please don't double post. Complete your other question to its logical conclusion. You have a correct answer in your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
INSERT INTO Food_Log (Person, Food, ServingSize, Date, Meal) VALUES
('John', 'Cheerios', 2, '2014-04-01', 'Breakfast'),
('John', 'TBoneSteak', 1, '2014-04-02', 'Lunch');
```

Comment: Since OP does not provide enough information, I tried to modify the query to the best I could do. I added the Date column since OP wrote 2 dates in each statement. I also changed the Date format in-case the Date column is actually formatted as a Date type not string. I also changed the semicolon to a comma since this is how multiple insert statements should look like.
Mind explaining the down vote please?

Comment: My apologies, I've been using SQL Server for years, but somehow I never knew you could insert multiple rows using that syntax.  I'm trying to adjust the vote but it won't let me for some reason.  It says it's locked in unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @user349065 -- Waiting period, I guess. I just let me up vote.